# Touching (click) matplotlib graph in kivy will crash

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, kivy

I build a small GUI to show some live data with kivy.

I added the matplotlib graph in my screen by doing this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot([1,2])

canvas = fig.canvas
self.ids.screen.add_widget(canvas, 2)
```

The rest of the GUI is designed with an `.kv` file. Everything works fine, but if I accidently touch the plot this occurs and no further touch is possible:

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 167, in <module>
     TestApp().run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 89, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 84, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 221, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-a56bsdeu-build/kivy/_event.c:7726)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1070, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-a56bsdeu-build/kivy/_event.c:7726)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1086, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-a56bsdeu-build/kivy/_event.c:7726)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-a56bsdeu-build/kivy/_event.c:7726)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (/tmp/pip-a56bsdeu-build/kivy/_event.c:7726)
   File "/home/sysop/.kivy/garden/garden.matplotlib/backend_kivy.py", line 1067, in on_touch_down
     if(touch.button == "scrollup" or touch.button == "scrolldown"):
 AttributeError: 'MTDMotionEvent' object has no attribute 'button'
```

What is the best way to avoid this?

Comment: Please use a more technical term like mouseover or click instead of touch.

Comment: Sorry, I use a touchscreen. Therefore, I wrote touch.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Didn't pay attention to "Kivy" in rapid reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved. I added in the graphic class:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    print " touch"
```

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4845